# Socket C# - Local Ip works, but Internet IP do not work

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

Guys, i implemented a Socket with Client and Server side.
When I use my local IP (192.168...) it works. But when I put the Internet IP, it doesn't work!
What's the main causes for that please?

Thank you

Comment: My guess would be firewall. What doesn't work? Do you get any error message? If you are on Windows Wireshark is quite good for monitoring this sort of stuff.

Comment: it's like this...i'm running both in my machine, so the IP of the client and server are the same
The code is like this:
http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/03/c-socket-programming/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a firewall or NAT device between you and the internet.

You should forward your port in your router.

Comment: This may or may not work.  If the OP is behind that firewall, then if his router doesn't support local loopback then he (she) won't be able to test the internet IP from within his local network.  Regardless, this isn't a software problem but a networking one.

Comment: Well, I already desactived my firewall, my anti-virus and ACTIVED the DMZ of the router that means I opened All Doors, but it still not work. Maybe I didnt really open the door =(

Comment: None of that matters -- if the router doesn't support local loopback of the WAN IP address, you cannot test the internet IP from behind your router.